# Elm 0.17: Task.perform and Maybe

Tags: elm

I'm hoping someone could help me with Task.perform as I don't really understand how to handle a Maybe response - and the docs aren't making things clearer for me.

In my `model` I have `results` which `Maybe` a list of items or `Nothing`.

```
-- model

type alias Item =
  { name : String}

type alias Model =
  { results : Maybe (List Item) }

model = {
  results = Nothing
}
```

I perform a Task and decode it like so:

```
-- Task

fetch : String -> Cmd Msg
fetch query =
  let url =
    "https://some_url" ++ query
  in
    Task.perform FetchFail FetchSuccess (Http.get decode url)


-- decoder

decoder: Json.Decoder (List Item)
decoder =
  Json.at ["data"] (Json.list nestedListDecoder)


-- nestedListDecoder

nestedListDecoder : Json.Decoder Item
nestedListDecoder =
  Json.object1 Item
    ("name" := Json.string)
```

I then handle the response in update:

```
-- update

type Msg
  = FetchSuccess (Maybe (List Item))
  | FetchFail Http.Error


update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
  case msg of
    FetchSuccess results ->
      case results of
        Nothing ->
          ( { model | results = Nothing}, Cmd.none)
        Just res ->
          ( { model | results = res }, Cmd.none)

    FetchFail err ->
      -- ... handle error
```

And cater for the Maybe in the view:

```
-- view

result : Item -> Html Msg
result item =
  li [] [ text item.name ]


view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
  ul [ ] (List.map result (Maybe.withDefault [] model.results))
```

I am getting this error when dealing with `Maybe` of results.

```
198|     Task.perform FetchFail FetchSuccess (Http.get repos url)
                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Function `perform` is expecting the 3rd argument to be:

    Task Http.Error (Maybe (List Repo))

But it is:

    Task Http.Error (List Repo)
```

Can anyone advise where else I need to cater for the `Maybe` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple tweak to your `decoder` should fix it. The decoder just needs to use [`Json.Decode.maybe`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/latest/Json-Decode#maybe):

```elm
decoder: Json.Decoder (Maybe (List Item))
decoder =
  Json.maybe <| Json.at ["data"] (Json.list nestedListDecoder)
```